# How to run a custom jar file copy to classpath command using java?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a jar file which I'm using to run as an application. However, every time I run my application I need to add -cp "jar name" to compile it and then run the java application.

How can I make a permanent change so that I don't have to use the command line commands for this task? Can I put that in certain lib location?

Note: I don't have to use any IDE. It has to be from a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Linux/ Mac, add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/jar
```

If you are on windows, use this..

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;\path\to\jar
```

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) and [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add your custom JAR in the `CLASSPATH`. Steps to setup and verify are available here: [JAVA PATH & CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Answer (score 1):

you may copy your lib or additional jars to JAVA_HOME/lib/ext
or any directory that is in system variable CLASSPATH

Answer (score 1):

One more solution: extension libraries, put your jar into  $JAVA_HOME/lib/ext

One needs to be careful - every java application will pick up this jar